# How can I make this request synchronous in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Here is my asynchronous code snippet its working properly by giving website urls this is an asynchronous request I want to make this a synchronous request 
can anyone help me here
I am using alchemy api to get the feeds
From cloud I am fetching the data

```js
 var urls = [website ur names]
 for(var j=0;j<urls.length;j++){
         alchemyapi.feeds("url",urls[j], {}, function(response) {
                     console.log(response["feeds"]);
                     for(var i=0;i<response["feeds"].length;i++)
                        var feed = response["feeds"][i].feed;
                        getFeed(feed);
                        console.log("Title: " +objToString(response["feeds"][i]));
        });
}
function objToString (obj) {
    var str = '';
    for (var p in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
            str += p + '::' + obj[p] + '\n';
        }
    }
    return str;
}
var request = require('request');
var getFeed = function(feed){

feeds = encodeURIComponent(feed);
request('http://cloud.example.com/v3/mixes/contents?streamId=feed/'+feeds/, function (error, response, body)
 {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) 
  {
    console.log(body)  
  }
  else 
  {
    console.log("Error "+response.statusCode)
  }
});
}
```

Comment: Synchronous request will make nodejs server block.I don't think there will be any situation,that fit the synchronous request.

Comment: no sir why it will block the nodejs server and i am fetching the data using alchemy api

Comment: by using promise js can't we make this synchronous @gumingfeng

Comment: Promise is build to avoid synchronous.In nodejs,javascript env is running in a  single thread.if there is a long time synchronous javascript function,no other javascript can be run.That is block.

Comment: Promise is just make the asynchronous scripts look more like synchronous ones.

Comment: If you know how to use promise
please help to implement the promise in this code 
I am  new to javascript i dont know how to implement this@gumingfeng

Answer (score 0):

```
var urls = [website ur names]

var request = require('request');

function promiseRequest(feeds){
  return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
    request('http://cloud.example.com/v3/mixes/contents?streamId=feed/'+feeds/,            
        function (error, response, body)    
     {
      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) 
      {
        resolve(body);
      }
      else 
      {
        reject(response.statusCode)；
      }
    });
  }
}

function getFeedsFromUrls(urls){
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        var count=0,totalCount = urls.length;
        var result=[];
        for(var j=0;j<urls.length;j++){
             alchemyapi.feeds("url",urls[j], {}, function(response) {
                 for(var i=0;i<response["feeds"].length;i++)
                    var feed = response["feeds"][i].feed;
                    promiseRequest(feed).then(function(data){
                        count++;
                        result.push(data);
                        if(count>=totalCount){
                            resolve(result);
                        }
                    }).catch(function(err){
                        count++;
                        if(count>=totalCount){
                            resolve(result);
                        }
                    });

            });
        }
    });
}

getFeedsFromUrls(urls).then(function(result){
    console.log(result);
})
```

Comment: should i call this from the loop or from outside?
and what is 'xxx'
btw thanks for the answer (y)